# Applying a specific css property to a child element while hovering on its previous sibling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a table that when you hover on one row it changes its background and bottom border color. Additionally I'd like to apply that same border color to its immediate sibling. Is there a way that this can be done using solely CSS?

**HTML**

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {width: 100%;}

tr {border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6; height: 40px;}

tr:hover {border-top: 1px solid #cadaee;}

tr:first-child {border-top: none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**adjacent sibling selector**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors), `+`.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/56Vje/)

```
tr:hover + tr {
    border-top: 1px solid #cadaee;
    height: 40px;
    background: #ebf4ff;
}
```

If you want both elements to be selected on `:hover`, use something like this instead:

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/56Vje/1/)

```
tr:hover + tr, tr:hover {
    border-top: 1px solid #cadaee;
    height: 40px;
    background: #ebf4ff;
}
```

Comment: The adjacent sibling selector in example #1 seemed to do the trick but only required the border-top property.

Comment: @CarlEdwards Oh - I thought you wanted the background too. Did you have any other questions?

Comment: Let's say I wanted to target an <hr> that rests directly above my first <tr> and change its color when I hover over only the first <tr>. Would I need to create an entirely new selector line or would I somehow be able to fit in the one listed in example #1?

Answer (score 0):

```
table {width: 100%;}

tr {border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6; height: 40px;}

tr:hover {border-top: 1px solid #cadaee; height: 40px; background: #ebf4ff;}

tr:hover + tr {border-top: 1px solid #cadaee;} /* Property that's applied to sibling */

tr:first-child {border-top: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Check this fiddle. This code running properly and what you expected. http://jsfiddle.net/webdevkumar/3bmmc/
```